# Maven: Empty profile active by default

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I have found out that most of poms in our project have defined a profile with exactly this definition:

```
    <profile>
        <id>default profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
```

Given there is no profile called "default profile" defined in any of the parent poms, that would do anything, I don't see a point in this. Is there any? Could it possibly override some default maven behaviour or anything, or can it be safely removed?

Comment: I would take a look into the version controll and see who has introduced it or cleaned it out and than remove it...cause an empty profile does not make sense?

Comment: It's been there since the initial commit, and has been reproduced to many poms ever since. Hence the question. It seems the same to me, but I don't want to remove it unless I'm 100% sure.

Comment: Than remove it cause an empty profiles does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is aged, but I've come across this:

I have a parent pom, configured to run some plugins. However, I only ever want to run these plugins for child poms. When I want to deploy "this" pom, I really only want that maven copies it into the repo. So I define an empty profile and activate it when I deploy the pom. Maybe it's a hack, but it's kind of nice to not have to rely on  and repeated plugin declarations in the child poms.